# Calling MFP adapter from independent IBM MFP client app

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

There are two different IBM MFP setup in two different network. Lets consider them A and B. Both are setup with same IBM MFP version 7.1.

Now problem is we want to call adapters from environment B in client application of environment A.

Can we call adapters from client application of A to B using `WLResourceRequest` as full URL.

Also let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Calling MFP Adapters of App A from App B is supported only if those adapter endpoints are kept unprotected. This case won't holds good with the protected adapter endpoints.

Comment: can we use WLResourceRequest for calling adapters of B from client application of A.

Comment: @2intor Yes, as you said you need to pass absolute URL as a parameter in WLResourceRequest API.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up adapter in one MFP environment as the confidential client of the other environment. Confidential clients can access resources protected by MobileFirst without coming in through a mobile device. 
And they can access protected resources too.

See how to do it with MFP v7.1 [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_non_mobile_to_mobile_services.html)

And with MFP v8 [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/confidential-clients/)

Comment: If i correctly understand you, first request will go through confidential client  A and then all adapter calls request will go to directly to environment B with the access token received from A. And is this going to happen for all unique devices or first device which is going to connect.

Comment: If you want to access an adapter from another MFP environment, you can pass the full URL. You have to use a condifential client only if you want to access an adapter from outside of a device